# Google Play services: Error while building ionic android app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play-services, android-sdk-tools

I am creating new ionic application. In this app I have added `Google Play services` package revision no. 31. Also added package to my app `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus`. This is used for google plus authentication.
So now I am facing problem while building android app using `ionic build android`. It gives me following error,
[image]

But when I remove the package `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-googleplus` and build the app it succeeds.

Is it because of the revision number of googleplus package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,
I have downgrade the following packages to previous revision.[image]

Remember you need to restart your machine if you are using windows to reflect changes in android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you Android SDK does not have Google Play Services installed. Therefore, it cannot compile your application which has Google Play Services reference (and Android SDK does not have those). Go to your Android SDK Manager and install Google Play Services for your android API version. PS you can see those errors in your console.

Comment: No, I have. As I mentioned above I have installed Google Play services revision no. 31. If I'm not wrong it is listed under 'Extras' in Android SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because this app is not using androidX but these plugins solve errors.Use these two plugin. Its solved my issue`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx && ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter`